# Override Default CSS Properties

Tags: css

i do have a wordpress theme with the default input CSS.

```
input, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"],     input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"],   input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input {
border: none !important;
background-color: #f0efed;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 16px;
color: #555;
border-radius: 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: :0px;
box-shadow: none !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
-moz-box-shadow: none !important;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
height: 40px;
}
```

I want to override the input styles such as 'text'and 'submit' in a specific div only.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="checkout_page_container">
<table class="checkout_cart">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I'm trying this CSS. But they wont work..

```
.checkout_page_container .checkout_cart input[type="text"] {
border: 1px solid #666;
}

.checkout_page_container .checkout_cart input[type="submit"] {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
color:#000;
}
```

When i do inpect element. the browsers still detects the default input styles of the theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the wordpress theme it has "border: none !important;" The !important means it won't be over written by styles with higher priority.

You can remove that to fix it, but it might break other things on the page(!important is a bit dirty and not good practice in most circumstances, so it's probably been used for a reason)

Answer (score 0):

Use "mystyle: value !important" and place the code *beneath* the WordPress stylesheet. This will override the WordPress' styles.

Comment: i heard that using !important is kinda dangerous?

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag Not that I know of. I only use !important when it's absolutely necessary.